# TypeError: encoding or errors without a string argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a list of data bytes to a CSV file. Since it's a list of byte strings, I used the below code:

```
with open(r"E:\Avinash\Python\extracting-drug-data\out.csv", "wb") as w:
    writer = csv.writer(w)
    writer.writerows(bytes(datas, 'UTF-8'))
```

But it results in the following error:

> TypeError: encoding or errors without a string argument

`datas` is a list of byte strings.

```
print(datas)
```

yields

```
[b'DB08873', b' MOLSDFPDBSMILESInChIView Structure \xc3\x97Structure for DB08873 (Boceprevir) Close', b'394730-60-0', b'LHHCSNFAOIFYRV-DOVBMPENSA-N', b'Organic acids and derivatives  ', b'Food increases exposure of boceprevir by up to 65% relative to fasting state. However, type of food and time of meal does not affect bioavailability of boceprevir and thus can be taken without regards to food.  \r\nTmax = 2 hours;\r\nTime to steady state, three times a day dosing = 1 day;\r\nCmax]
```

I want the above list to be printed as first row in a CSV file with the decoding of Unicode chars. That is, `\xc3\x97` should be converted to it's corresponding character.

Comment: Since you want to convert bytes back to string, shouldn't it be `str(datas, 'UTF-8')` instead? (Also, shouldn't you apply it to each of the elements, instead of the entire list?)

Comment: Also, for `writerows`, shouldn't `datas` be a list of lists?

Comment: @tobias_k shows `TypeError: coercing to str: need a bytes-like object, list found`

Comment: Still not sure I really understood what you are trying to do. Could you please post the exact `datas` you are using and how exactly that is supposed to look in the CSV? (There is a `'` missing in `datas`, so this seems to be cropped.) Also, how are the `\n` supposed to be rendered in CSV, and is this supposed to be a single row, or multiple rows?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems your `datas` *is* already in bytes format, so to turn it into UTF-8 strings, you have to use `str`, not `bytes`! Also, you have to convert each element from `datas` individually, not the entire list at once. Finally, if you want to add `datas` as one row to `out.csv`, you have to use `writerow`, whereas `writerows` would write *all* the rows at once, and accordinly would expect a list of lists.

Depending on your OS, you might also have to specify the `encoding` when opening the file. Otherwise it will use the OS' default encoding, which might be something entirely different.

This *seems* to do what you want. The result is a CSV file with one row<sup>1</sup> of data in UTF-8 format, and the `\xc3\x97` is decoded to `×`.

```
import csv
with open(r"out.csv", "w", encoding='UTF-8') as w:
    writer = csv.writer(w)
    writer.writerow([str(d, 'UTF-8') for d in datas])
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> Note that the last item in `datas` contains some line breaks, and thus will be split onto several lines. This is probably not what you want. Or is this a glitch in your `datas` list?

Comment: Addendum: If you want to decode the unicode but keep `\n` escaped, you could try `repr(str(d, 'UTF-8'))`, but I'm not sure whether that's what you want. This will also wrap all the strings in `''`

Comment: tried that , but it shows `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`

Comment: @AvinashRaj I got that error to, fixed it by changing the file mode from `wb` to `w`. (I don't think that `b` (binary) makes sense for a CSV file) Sorry, forgot to mention that change.

Comment: it drives me crazy. If i removed the `b` in `wb`, it displays `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u221e'`. It fails to convert a unicode char to string.

Comment: If you have some time, just jump into http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80049/temp . I'm going to set a bounty for this..

Answer (score 5):

This error just means the thing you're passing to `bytes` (the string you want converted to a byte sequence) is not in fact a string. It does *not* specifically mean that the argument is already of type `bytes`, just that it *isn't* a string.

```
>>> bytes(b"", encoding="utf-8")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: encoding without a string argument
>>> bytes(None, encoding="utf-8")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: encoding without a string argument
>>> bytes(12, encoding="utf-8")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: encoding without a string argument
```